# Tesseract OCR for .net not detecting text when white text is written on black rectangle and the border of black rectangle is white?

Tags: c#, png, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to extract a text from a png using tesseract. Tesseract doesn't extract text in case of following png. [image]

The black rectangle in the image has white border(which is not visible because of website background).But, in case, I remove white border off the rectangle then Tesseract is able to detect the text.Is there any work around for this issue?

Also, if the decrease the border size then it does extract some text as:

> I (31.04 I

Here is the code that I am using:

```
 using (TesseractEngine ocr = new TesseractEngine(dataPath, "eng", EngineMode.TesseractOnly))
            {
                using (Pix p = Pix.LoadFromFile(filePath))
                {
                    using (Pix img = p.Scale(2,3))
                    {

                        using (var page = ocr.Process(img))
                        {

                            string text = page.GetText();
                            Console.WriteLine(text);
                        } 
                    }
                }

            }
```

By scaling I am able to extract following text:

> I G1.04 I

However, if I increase the border size then even scaling the image has no effect.

Comment: Actually Tesseract can detect text even with the white borders. It might be due to someother issue. Try Converting the image to greyscale and pass it to tesseract

Comment: "scale" fixed my issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
using AForge.Imaging;
Grayscale grayFilter = new Grayscale(0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721);
Bitmap grImage = grayFilter.Apply(image);
grImage.Save("./grey_image.png");
```

Pass this image path to your **TesseractEngine.**

Comment: Used this code, but it doesn't make any difference.Also, the png is black and white.So, I don't think the resultant greyscale image is any different from the original one.But I did notice that if I decrease the white border width then it does detect text as "I (31.04 I".

Comment: You should pre process your image before giving the image tesseract engine

Comment: What shall I do in this image preprocessing?

Comment: Check this link for some tips: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ImproveQuality